# The Work Items Page in TFS 2018.2 is Missing

Tags: tfs

According to the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/view-add-work-items

the new work items page is available in TFS 2018.2 which we are running.  But it is not showing up on the Work menu.

Is this something we need to enable or did it not make it into 2018.2?

Comment: Can you share your TFS screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be an document issue, based on my test the work item page only available on Azure DevOps (VSTS) for now.

Tested on both TFS 2018.2 and TFS 2018.3 and cannot see the work item page.

---

**UPDATE:**

It's an document issue based on KathrynEE's comment in this thread: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2134

> The Work Items page isn't available from TFS 2018.2. It will be
>   available with the RC1 release of TFS 2019, now known as Azure DevOps
>   Server 2019.

Comment: Thank you for checking your TFS instance.  I have opened an issue on Github to confirm:  https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2134